# Show image over entire screen on OS X

Tags: image, macos, screenshot, osx-mountain-lion

Is there a way to show an image over the entire screen in OS X?

The goal is to "freeze" the screen by taking a screenshot and overlaying it over the screen. Note that the fullscreen mode would not work well for this; the new image would have to replace the old one without any animation so that it looks as though the screen was frozen.